# Gitlab CI with Docker and NPM

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab

I'm trying to setup a basic pipeline in Gitlab that does the following:
Run tests command, compile the client and deploy the application using docker-compose.

The problem comes when I'm trying to use `npm install`.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your 
project.
# Official docker image.
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
 - test
 - build
 - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd packages/public/client/
    - npm install --only=production
    - npm run build
test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - develop
    - production
  script:
    - echo run tests in this section

step-deploy-production:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - production
script:
  - docker-compose up -d --build
environment: production
when: manual
```

And the error is:

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ cd packages/public/client/
$ npm install --only=production
bash: line 69: npm: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I'm using the last docker image, so, I'm wondering whether I can define a new service on my build stage or should I use a different image for the whole process?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new service [will not help you](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-services-are-not-for), you'll need to use a different image.
You can use a node image just for your `build`-stage like this:

`build:
  image: node:8
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd packages/public/client/
    - npm install --only=production
    - npm run build`

Comment: @lucaswerner: In case you're satisfied with my answer, please click the big checkbox to accept it.