# Installing NPM during build fails Docker build

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to get GitLab CI runner to build my project off the Docker image and install NPM package during the build. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file was inspired by this topic [Gitlab CI with Docker and NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823047/gitlab-ci-with-docker-and-npm) where the PO was dealing with identical problem:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1

compile:
  image: node:8
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py recreate_db
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py seed_db
    - npm install
    - bash test.sh


after_script:
  - docker-compose down
```

Sadly, that solution didn't work well but I feel like I'm little bit closer to actual solution now. I'm getting two errors during the build:

```
/bin/bash: line 89: apk: command not found
Running after script...
$ docker-compose down
/bin/bash: line 88: docker-compose: command not found
```

How can I troubleshoot this ?

**Edit:**

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py recreate_db
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py seed_db

testing:
  image: node:alpine
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - bash test.sh


after_script:
  - docker-compose down
```

I moved tests into separate stage `testing` which I should've done anyway and I figured I'd defined the image there to separate it from the build stage. No change. Docker can't be found and bash test also can't be ran:

```
$ bash test.sh
/bin/sh: eval: line 87: bash: not found
Running after script...
$ docker-compose down
/bin/sh: eval: line 84: docker-compose: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

`image: node:8` this image is not based on alpine so as a result, you got error

> apk: command not found

`node:<version>`

> These are the suite code names for **releases of Debian** and indicate
>   which release the image is based on. If your image needs to install
>   any additional packages beyond what comes with the image, you'll
>   likely want to specify one of these explicitly to minimize breakage
>   when there are new releases of **Debian**.

just replace image to

```
node:alpine
```

and it should work.

the second error is because docker-compose is not installed.

You can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775954/sudo-docker-compose-command-not-found) for more details about composer.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, Docker installation is failing because the line with `apk` where I install all necessary packages is failing. **As soon as remove `image: node:<whatever>`** all runs just fine and app is built.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tick it as a solution because the Node image keeps overriding Docker image for some reason. Still wrestling with it.

Comment: How it overrides

Comment: I don't understand it either. As long as the Node image is there Docker doesn't have a chance to work. I'm gonna update the post to reflect how my file looks like now.